# Произвольный вывод количество строк в sql - LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, limit

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста, как установить кастомную переменную для количества строк выводимых с mysql
Есть -

```
$query="SELECT nam3 , COUNT(*) AS total FROM lottoindex
    WHERE nam3 > 0 GROUP BY nam3 
    ORDER BY nam3+ 0 ASC
    ";
```

Необходимо добавить LIMIT "myvar"
Где "myvar" это число которое ввел пользователь в инпут... Заранее очень благодарен

Comment: Не совсем понятно в чем сложность. Получить число которое пользователь ввел получается? Если да, то просто добавь в $query "LIMIT X".

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="SELECT nam3 , COUNT(*) AS total FROM lottoindex
WHERE nam3 > 0 GROUP BY nam3 
ORDER BY nam3+ 0 ASC";
if (isset($_GET['count'] && is_numeric($_GET['count'])){
    $query .= ' LIMIT '.$_GET['count'];
}
```

где html

```
<input name="count">
```

Comment: А по-человечески?

Comment: LIMIT $myvar это впринципе и написано в вопросе, как передать значение с инпута что бы вывело нужное количество строк

Comment: Отредактировал ответ

Comment: @ Anton Shchyrov 500 error